# How isolate scope by attribute with value type uuid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to make a dashboard with widgets. The data (json object) that must be displayed on widgets cam from server by ajax request at every n seconds. Every widget has uuid type identifier. I have tryed using directive isolated scope, but it didn't work form me with uuid type. Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/djOB4UjS8HL9awS6CDeO?p=preview) example.

How to make this code working?
Or maybe there is better ways to acomplish this goal with angularjs ?

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="dashboard">
  <div ng-controller="widgetController as ctrl">
    <widget id="ctrl.cbdf9d33-8d7a-43f7-a8b5-5b011edd2402"></widget>
    <widget id="ctrl.5ed23c32-a443-45eb-932e-8ff1d23a912f"></widget>
    <widget id="ctrl.2de16396-88a3-48cd-b42a-bc30bdd80064"></widget>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### script.js

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('dashboard', [])
    .controller('widgetController', ['$interval', '$http', function($interval, $http) {
      var vm = this;

      var updateWidgetsLoop = $interval(function() {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'server.json'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          var widgets = response.data;
          angular.forEach(widgets, function(widget, key) {
            vm[key] = widget;
          });
        });
      }, 5000);
    }])
    .directive('widget', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          id: '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{id.value}}</div>',
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

### server.json

```
{
 "cbdf9d33-8d7a-43f7-a8b5-5b011edd2402" : {"value": 10},
 "5ed23c32-a443-45eb-932e-8ff1d23a912f" : {"value": 20},
 "2de16396-88a3-48cd-b42a-bc30bdd80064" : {"value": 30}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you html code

```
<widget id="ctrl.cbdf9d33-8d7a-43f7-a8b5-5b011edd2402"></widget>
```

to

```
<widget id="ctrl['cbdf9d33-8d7a-43f7-a8b5-5b011edd2402']"></widget>
```

It should work. Good Luck :-)

Working Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/SmJtaItdB7lrgxu0GbiP?p=preview

Hope it solved you problem :-)